# prove that the space $C^{\infty}(R_{+}^n)\cap W^{1,2}(R_{+}^n)$ is dense in $W^{1,2}(R_{+}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I already know that as $C^{\infty}_c(R^n)$ is dense in $W^{1,2}(R^n)$, but I don't know why the space $C^{\infty}(R_{+}^n)\cap W^{1,2}(R_{+}^n)$ is dense in  $W^{1,2}(R_{+}^n)$

Is the statement true and why?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess by $R^n_+$ you mean a half space of the form $R^{n-1}\times (0,\infty)$? In that case $C^\infty(R^n_+)$ is not even contained in $H^1(R^n_+)$. But their intersection is indeed dense in $H^1(R^n_+)$ by the usual convolution argument.

Comment: yes, $R_{+}^n$ means $R^{n-1}\times(0,\infty)$. Why their intersection is dense in $H^1(R_{+}^n)$, can you give me an explanation? thank you !

Comment: and $H^1$ means $W^{1,2}$ in this book I read. :)

Comment: Look up the Meyers-Serrin theorem. The original paper is quite short and approachable: http://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/51/6/1055.full.pdf

Comment: thank you! does this statement can be extended to a more general case? and is this a general approach to solve the density problem? I'm very confused with those definitions and statements when I'm learning, and I don't know where to get the right answer or exact resources.

Comment: If by "more general case" you mean different domains with boundary, then yes, it is already done in the linked paper.

Comment: understand, thanks a lot!